# Which atmospheric factors that can affect the performance of an aircraft while flying a circuit?

Tags: traffic-pattern

Which atmospheric factors that can affect the performance of an aircraft while flying a circuit?  Apart from the general wind shift.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I'm not sure what you're asking: the factors that affect an aircraft's performance apply in all stages of flight and there's nothing special about being in the circuit. You might want to browse [our questions on aircraft performance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-performance) and perhaps narrow down your question to be more specific. The [tour] may be useful as well, if you aren't familiar with how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

In short, all of them. Environmental factors that affect aircraft performance do so whenever that aircraft is flying, regardless of whether you're flying a circuit, a straight line, or anything in between. The most important environmental factors include:

- wind speed
- wind direction
- air temperature
- air density
- air pressure

Comment: Plus visibility, ceiling, precipitation?